# cURL Not returning response and not sending post data

Tags: php, curl

So I am looking into an issue I have been having yet again and it is still frustrating. All I want to do is upload a file to a remote location using a cURL request and I have zero success regardless of any type of research and examples I try. I will begin will posting each bit of code and giving a small explanation with specific problems for each.

Here is my curl_handler:

**curlUploadHandler.php**

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1216.0 Safari/537.2");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$post_array = array(
    "file" => "@".$_FILES['doc']['tmp_name'][$i],
    "upload" => "Upload",
    "type" => $type
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_array);

$r = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($r);
curl_close($ch);
```

the above code is the portion of the code where I do the curl handling and there is something wrong with how it is organized, or ordered, or something, but I can not figure out what.

**upload.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $addr){
    if(!empty($_FILES['file'])){
        $type = $_POST['type'];
        $directory = "/var/www/assets/$type/";
        if($_FILES['file']['error'] > 0){
            $response['errors'] = true;
            $response['error'] = $_FILES['file']['error'];
        }else{
            if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $directory.$_FILES['file']['name'])){
                $response['errors'] = true;
                $response['error'] = 9;
            }else{
                $response['errors'] = false;
            }
        }
    }else{
        $response['errors'] = true;
        $response['error'] = 9;
    }
}else{
    $response['errors'] = true;
    $response['error'] = 9;
}
```

this is the upload handler on the remote side. Now the interesting thing is when I attempt to send data from `curlUploadHandler.php` I will get that the file successfully uploaded, but that is because there is no data being send to `upload.php`. I will get zero response from `upload.php` no matter what I try, I have done this set up way too many different ways, over and over and over again, and have had no success. Can somebody please help me find a solution?

I thank everyone in advance for their patience and help.

**UPDATE**

it seems when I removed the `@` symbol from `file` in `$post_array` it works, but it won't send as a file, so now I'm really confused because every example shows that `@` symbol work and it's failing for me!

If I run a `curl_getinfo($ch);` if gives me this array of information:

```
array(22) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(46) "http://portal.hoovestol.local/upload/index.php"
  ["content_type"]=>
  NULL
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(0)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(0)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(0)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(0.063)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0.063)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(-1)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(-1)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

From what it looks like the script is never actually hitting the directory that I am trying to land on.

Comment: 1. What PHP version are you using?  2. Does `$_FILES['doc']['tmp_name'][$i]` point to a valid, readable file on the server?

Comment: 1. version 5.3 :/ (not allowed to update boss doesn't want to) 2. yes

Comment: I'd recommend trying the following to debug further: `var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));` after `curl_exec`, if that doesn't give any useful info, add `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('php://output', 'w'));` to have debug output sent to PHP from cURL.

Comment: @drew010 I did the `var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch))` I having pasted the results uptop. The other option caused an error and crashed the program.